# Listview Item is always null

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to populate listview  with some registry information using this code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvItem = null;
    RegistryKey uninstallKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(UninstallPath);
    if (uninstallKey != null)
        foreach (var subKey in uninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = uninstallKey.OpenSubKey(subKey))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    lvItem =
                        new ListViewItem(key.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString());
                    lvItem.SubItems.Add(key.GetValue("Publisher").ToString());
                }
            }
            listView1.Items.Add(lvItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is okay while debugging the application. There is nothing null until the breakpoint hits here

```
lvItem = new ListViewItem(key.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString());
lvItem.SubItems.Add(key.GetValue("Publisher").ToString());
```

application crashes and gives me the null pointer exception. I know it's a silly question but I really don't understand how could it be null.

Comment: I guess that `key.GetValue("DisplayName")` returns `null`, then it crashes   at `ToString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `key.GetValue("Publisher").ToString()`, use `(string)key.GetValue("Publisher")` instead. This is because `GetValue` can return null and if you try `.ToString()` on null you will get that exception.